# how to insert latitude and logitude with for loop in google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am using google maps in my project I have created the map but I am not able to pass the latitude and longitude from my API how can I solve this.

I am getting msg like i have shown on Image, I don't want to display that msg but when I click on it I have to see a pop up and some Information, how can do that.

TYpescript code:

```
       map_dev:any = []
       getMapData(){
         this.service.getmap_data().subscribe(response =>{
           this.map_dev = response
          })
        }

      @ViewChild("mapContainer", { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;
      map: google.maps.Map;
      lat = 40.73061;
      lng = -73.935242;


     markers = [
     {

     position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.73061, 73.935242),
     map: this.map,
     title: "Marker 1"
     },
    {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.06485, 34.763226),
    map: this.map,
    title: "Marker 2"
   }
   ];

   //Coordinates to set the center of the map
   coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);

   mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
   center: this.coordinates,
   zoom: 2,
   streetViewControl:false,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

  //Default Marker
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: this.coordinates,
  map: this.map,
  title: '<div class="info-window">'+
        '<h3>Info Window Content</h3>'+
        '<div class="info-content">'+
        '<div>'+
       '</div>'
  });

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.mapInitializer();
  }

 mapInitializer(): void {
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);

   //Adding Click event to default marker
   this.marker.addListener("click", () => {
   const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: this.marker.getTitle()
   });
   infoWindow.open(this.marker.getMap(), this.marker);
  });

   //Adding default marker to map
   this.marker.setMap(this.map);

   //Adding other markers
   this.loadAllMarkers();
  }

  loadAllMarkers(): void {
    this.markers.forEach(markerInfo => {
    //Creating a new marker object
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    ...markerInfo
   });

   //creating a new info window with markers info
  const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: marker.getTitle()
  });

  marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
  });


  //Add click event to open info window on marker
    marker.addListener("click", () => {
    infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);

   });

  //Adding marker to google map
  marker.setMap(this.map);
 });
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do and what error you're getting. Please can you clarify and provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?